# Is it possible to wrap controller's method call with custom code using one of System.Web.HttpApplication events?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-5.1

What I want to do: log the start of request and the end of request with the same correlation token (guid, created on start and passed to the end). Also this correlation token should be available in the controller.

May be overriding HttpApplication controller's method functionality could help me in that?

OK. MSDN call them events, but the possibility to instantiate controller and call its method in the Application_Error made an impression on me so I still have hope that my problem also could be solved.

P.S. Of course I could do the same with the custom code inside action, but interested in something more universal.

Comment: If you use an IoC container like Autofac, have you looked at Interceptors? http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/interceptors.html

Comment: I know how interceptors works but how they would help me to put my code to the end of request? I not like the idea to log from controller's dispose. If the proposed solution is to return from container not controller but with codedom created specific proxy to the controller (with logging injected) - simpler to generate such proxy with T4 and use it "expliecetly". Actually I'm thinking if you have access to all code - interceptors are excessive always.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a custom DelegatingHandler for that and add it to the MessageHandlers of the HttpConfiguration. This will grant you access to the HttpRequestMessage before the action is executed and to the HttpResponseMessage after the action is executed.

All described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/http-message-handlers